# UTC to Local Time conversion using Perl minimal installed Modules

Tags: perl, datetime

I want to convert time which is in UTC to localtime. I found a solution for this using `Time::Piece` module.

The problem here is, the machine I am putting my script doesn't have `Time::Piece` module installed. Its having Perl version `v5.10.1` with minimal installation.

Here is the script which I tried (This is working fine in my local machine which has `Perl v5.26.3`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw( );
use Time::Piece;

sub utc_to_local {
    my ($utc_ts) = @_;
    my $utc_tp = Time::Piece->strptime( $utc_ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' );
    my $local_tp = localtime($utc_tp->epoch);
    return $local_tp->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
}

my $utc = "2020-08-18T16:28:45";
($utc = $utc) =~ s/T/ /;

my $local = utc_to_local($utc);
print "UTC: $utc ** local: $local\n";
```

So, using `POSIX` or `Time::Local`(Or any other inbuilt Perl modules which comes under `Perl v5.10.1`) how can I convert UTC to localtime.
(Please don't suggest me to install Perlbrew).

Comment: `Time::Piece` should be part of Perl's core since 5.10, having first appeared in 5.9.5. Are you sure, `perl -MTime::Piece -e 1` fails?

Comment: @JRFerguson: Yep, its failing. `Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.`

Comment: I _believe_ older Redhat-based distributions separated a lot of the core Perl modules into a `perl-core` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get around the fact that you can't seem to find `Time::Piece` this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Time::Local;

my $utc = '2020-08-18T16:28:45';   

my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = ((reverse(split /\D/,$utc))[0..5]);
my $time = timegm($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, ($mon-1), $year);

print strftime "%Y-%m-%dT%T UTC\n", gmtime($time);
print strftime "%Y-%m-%dT%T %Z %z\n", localtime($time);

$ENV{TZ} = 'America/Los_Angeles';
print strftime "%Y-%m-%dT%T %Z %z\n", localtime($time);
```

I'm in the Eastern US and when run, gives:

```
2020-08-18T16:28:45 UTC
2020-08-18T12:28:45 EDT -0400
2020-08-18T09:28:45 PDT -0700
```

Answer (score 2):

Time::Piece was included as a standard module in Perl 5.10.0

```
$ corelist Time::Piece

Data for 2020-07-17
Time::Piece was first released with perl v5.9.5
```

So what's going on here?

I assume you're using RHEL5 (or a distribution, like Centos, that was built on it).

In that version of RHEL, the standard Perl distribution was split into two RPMs, called `perl` and `perl-core`. Only the `perl` RPM was installed as part of the default RHEL build. And that leaves you missing a large chunk of the bits of Perl that you'd expect to find; including Time::Piece. It was a terrible decision by Red Hat and one that confuses Perl programmers to this day.

But the solution is simple. You just need to install the `perl-core` RPM to get all of the missing pieces of Perl 5.10.

```
$ sudo yum install perl-core
```

If you don't have `sudo` access, then you'll need to find someone who does. They can't expect you to write and run Perl code on a machine with a crippled version of Perl.

Comment: _Perl distribution was split into two RPMs, called `perl` and `perl-core`.._ you're right. The distribution was `perl` in the system which I am writing scripts.

Comment: @vkk05: Ok, so now you know how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, Dave. I remember you suggested same when I had similar problem in Perl Module dependency.  But when the system upgrade happens I don't know the system will come to default state. (As a core Perl Developer I totally agree the point _They can't expect you to write and run Perl code on a machine with a crippled version of Perl_).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. But drawback is I am shelling out the `date` command.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $datetime = "2020-08-18T16:28:45";
print "UTC: $datetime\n";

($datetime = $datetime) =~ s/T/ /g;
my $local_time  = `date -d '$datetime UTC' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`; chomp $local_time;

print "Localtime:$local_time\n";
```

I still prefer @JRFerguson's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63490770/6124824).

Comment: You could just use `+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` instead of changing the `T` to a space...

Comment: `($datetime = $datetime)` is a very weird way of writing `$datetime`